# no puedo logearme con laravel estoy usando el 5.4

Tags: android, laravel

¿Me pueden ayudar? No sé en cuál me equivoco, no sé qué más hacer, he intentado de todo. Este es mi código:

este es mi **controlador**:

```
<?php

namespace Inventario\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inventario\Http\Requests;
use Inventario\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Inventario\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LogController extends Controller
{    
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(UserRequest $request)


{


    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request, 'password' => $request]))
    {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
    Session::flash('message-error','Datos son incorrectos');
    return Redirect::to('/');
}

public function logout(){
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

este es mi **vista**:

```
@extends('layouts.principal')
@section('content')
@include('alerts.errors')
@include('alerts.request')
            <div class="header">
        <div class="top-header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                <p>Movie Theater</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-info">
            <h1>BIG HERO 6</h1>
            {!!Form::open(['route'=>'log.store', 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!!Form::label('correo','Correo:')!!}   
                    {!!Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingresa tu correo'])!!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!!Form::label('contrasena','Contraseña:')!!}   
                    {!!Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ingresa tu contraseña'])!!}
                </div>
                {!!Form::submit('Iniciar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
            {!!Form::close()!!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-slider">
         <ul id="flexiselDemo1">
        <li><img src="images/r1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li><img src="images/r2.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li><img src="images/r3.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li><img src="images/r4.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li><img src="images/r5.jpg" alt=""/></li>
        <li><img src="images/r6.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
@endsection
```

este es mi **modelo**;

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($valor){
    if(!empty($valor)){
        $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($valor);
    }
}
}
```

est es mi **config/auth.php**

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' =>Inventario\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

No sé en cuál fallo, si pueden ayudarme, sería de mucha ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esta línea esta mal `Auth::attempt(['email' => $request, 'password' => $request])`
debe ser `Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])`.

Estoy tomando en cuenta que la clase **UserRequest** hereda de la clase **Request**, la cual se encarga de recibir la información enviada a través de formularios sino solo cambia a **Request** el tipo de dato de `$request` en tu método **store**